# Melody transcription from microphone

Tags: web-apps, osx, music, iphone-app, music-composing

I'd like the simplest possible software that can convert an audio file of an instrument into a musical score. I specifically want to use this for quickly grabbing violin melodies to a musical score for practicing and sharing. Support for guitar melodies, and chords would be excellent. Support for piano and dulcimer would be nice to have.

Ideally the program would have the 'record' functionality built in, but importing an already existing wav and processing it would be okay.

It could expect a roughly studio quality input (isolated, and good signal quality) but providing some UI to show levels would be helpful.

Basic adjustments/corrections to notes would be required, unless the transcription was perfect every time :)

Printing the score would be required (or saving as PDF, etc.), and exporting a midi file would be handy.